# Route attributes range constraint vs range attribute validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

With the new Attribute Routing and its constraints it seems the border why I should use attributes to validate my DTO`s gets blurry more and more.

I can do a Range validation on 2 ways now - consider that the first approach has an action with a complex class + Weight property -

When should I use which approach and what are their advantages vs the other approach?

```
[Range(0,500)]
public int Weight {get;set;}
```

vs

```
[GET("{id:range(0, 500)}")]
public Machine GetMachine(int weight)
{

}
```

The first approach result in a Bad Request.

The second approach result in a Not Found Request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last two sentences summarize it well. In the case of `[Range]`, that sets up *validation of the input* so it can tell the caller their request was bad. In the second, it's defining rules for matching a URL to the route, which would be used for sending requests to different routes, not for validating input. The second could be useful, for example, if you have IDs of different formats that you want to handle with different methods.

In short, the UX for the first would be "I must be sending invalid data" and for the second "I must have the wrong URL."

**Update**:

Here's a demonstration of what I meant for how to use the route attribute for different formats:

```
[GET("/users/{id:int}")]
public User GetUserById(int id)
{

}

[GET("/users/{email:regex(^[^@]+@[^@]$)}")]
public User GetUserByEmail(string email)
{

}

[GET("/users/{username}")]
public User GetUserByName(string username)
{

}
```

Comment: "...if you have IDs of different formats that you want to handle with different methods." I do not understand this, would you mind slapping 2 actions in your answer? :-)

Comment: @Pascal, updated the answer. Hopefully is more clear.

Comment: So the Route constraints define actually ONE route. The difference is resolved at runtime which action is choosen finally. Yes... but still I do not know yet wether I should use now validation range or constraint range. Hm...

Comment: It depends. If someone provided a weight that was out of range, do you want to tell them the resource is not found or that the request was bad? I'd guess you'd want the latter (`Range` attribute).

Comment: Well this is to be discussed in our team tomorrow then ;-)